# Sass 3.3 RC1 in Rails app using sass-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sass

I want to update my in development Rails app to use the newly released Sass 3.3 RC1. How can I do this if I am using the sass-rails gem?

Answer (score 2):

You merely refer to the master branch of the github repository in this case; Was able to immediately use Sass 3.3 RC! with zero issues within the context of Rails.

Don't forget to upgrade Compass as well the same way:

```
 gem "compass", github: "chriseppstein/compass"

 gem "compass-rails", github: "Compass/compass-rails"
```

**Update: merely typing `bundle update` worked for me on another Rails 4 project to get Sass 3.3.rc1**

Comment: Thanks but how do I use sass 3.3 when sass is being used as a dependency if the sass-rails gem or do I remove sass rails and just use the sass gem on its own?

Comment: You're right about that; I tried using the Sass 3.3.rc1 features in the context of a Rails 4 app that had successfully uploaded it yesterday only for the new features not being recognized as valid syntax.

I have been able to use all the new features outside of Rails that I'm aware of.. the new string functions, data mapping, and so on I was exposed to during the summer. 

Have you had any luck removing Sass-Rails? Will try to do so myself when I get access to my Rails projects later tonight